# angular 2 -spring boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot

i'am trying to implement autentication service to connect from a frontend application written in angular2 to a backend service written in spring boot.
i'am also trying to use jwt token for connection.

here is my code:

angular2 :

```
    login(id : number, username: string, password: string): 
    Observable<boolean> 
   {
      return this.http.post('/api/authenticate', JSON.stringify({id: id, 
      username: username, password: password }))
           .map((response: Response) => {
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            let token = response.json() && response.json().token;
            if (token) {
                // set token property
                this.token = token;

                // store username and jwt token in local storage to keep 
user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ 
 username: username, token: token }));

                // return true to indicate successful login
                return true;
            } else {
                // return false to indicate failed login
                return false;
            }
        });
}
```

backend :

```
 public ResponseEntity<?> login(@RequestBody User user) throws 
 ServletException {

    String jwtToken="";

    if(user.getName() == null || user.getPassword() == null) {
            throw new ServletException("Utilisateur ou mot de passe non valide");
    }

    String username = user.getName();
    String password = user.getPassword();

    User user1 = userService.findByName(username);
    if(user1 == null) {
        throw new ServletException("Utilisateur non trouvé");
    }

    String pwd = user1.getPassword();

    if(!password.equals(pwd)){
         throw new ServletException("login invalide. Verifiez login et mot de passe");
    }

    jwtToken = Jwts.builder().setSubject(username).claim("roles", "user").setIssuedAt(new Date())
                   .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, "secretkey").compact();

    return new ResponseEntity<String>(jwtToken, HttpStatus.OK);     
}
```

i got this error in the backend :
Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported
Can anyone help me please? thanks in advance :)

Comment: looks like the content-type is not set in the angular code. try setting the header `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: yeah that's it :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your Spring Boot application is expecting a request of `Content-Type` equal to `application/json`.  Since you didn't set a content-type, [the browser are setting a default one for you](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/history.html#content-type-sniffing) (`text/plain;charset=UTF-8`).

So All you have to do is specifying you request content-type as below :

```
let op = new BaseRequestOptions();
op.headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
this.http.post(url, body, op)...
```

Answer (score 0):

Radouane is right. On top of that, why don't you use an Angular2 spring Boot jwt starter kit? It would make your life a lot easier. There are plenty starter kit on Github, the one I'm using is [angular-spring-starter](https://github.com/bfwg/angular-spring-starter)